# Run php script in linux server from another php script using ssh and shell

Tags: php, linux, shell, ssh, phpseclib

I can run a php script which is located in linux server as follows:

```
nclude('/Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('ip address');
if (!$ssh->login('user name', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('/usr/bin/nohup php  /path/to/script/run.php > /path/to/log/run_log.log 2>&1 &');
```

Now I need to add some code as follows so that it will reply finish of the job.

```
$output = shell_exec('if [ $? -eq "0" ];then echo "All done" else echo "Not Work" fi');
echo $output;
```

But it is not working. Means `run.php` runs in linux server but when it is finished, `$output` does not print anything.  Could you please help?

Comment: please, provide more details about "is not working". Otherwise the question is unsalvageable.

Comment: @Jakuje - I have edited above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my answer:

```
$pid=0;
$pid=$ssh->exec("(ps -ef | grep run.php | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')");

while ($pid >0)
{
echo "Process id when running=".$pid."\n";
$pid =$ssh->exec("(ps -ef | grep run.php | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')");
}
echo "Process is not running \n";
```

**Explanation:**
From Linux the output will be as bellow

```
bash-3.2$ ps -ef | grep run.php 
506       1455     1   3 10:56 ?        00:00:02 /path/to/script/run.php
```

So awk '{print $2}' will provide value 1455 which is the pid of the process